# Square Roots: Variables with Exponents.

Tags: divisibility, exponentiation, square-numbers

Alright, so let me get this straight:

$\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$

$\sqrt{x^3} = x\sqrt{x}$

$\sqrt{x^4} = x^2$

$\sqrt{x^6} = |x^3|$

Are these correct?

Comment: Yes. In fact, sqrt(x^4)=sqrt((x^2)^2), and sqrt(x^6)=sqrt((x^3)^2), so these are just compositions of the other two functions. In fact any exponent can be re-written as the composition of square and cubes. I hope this helps you see the underlying pattern.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand. So what I have above is all correct?

Comment: Yes. You could say that $\sqrt{x^3}=|x|\sqrt x$, but the domain is $x\ge0$ so it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: Well, yes. It certainly is, I just mean that the sqrt(x^4) and sqrt(x^6) can be trivially determined given you know the other two

Answer (score 0):

Well The first and last one are more tricky than the other two.

you know that $x^2$ is always positive and so when we take the square root it will be also positive, This is why $$\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$$

And the last one follows from the first one, But here you have to know that the an even power is always positive $x^{2n}$ is always positive for any positive integer $n$ and since $6$ is even then $x^6$ is positive and so 
$$\sqrt{x^6} = |(x^6)^\frac{1}{2}| = |x^3|$$

Notice that we evaluate inside out, so we first take $x^6$ then we apply the square root that's why we get the absolute value equivalence.

The 2nd and 3rd ones are very easy.

$$\sqrt{x^3} = (x^3)^\frac{1}{2} = x^\frac{3}{2} = xx^\frac{1}{2} = x\sqrt{x}$$

and the last one follows the same way

You are right !

Comment: So is true that $\sqrt{x^{2n}} = |x^n|$, with $x \geq 0$ ?